# Nunit Test A C# Model

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I have done some Unit Testing for controllers. Is there a way of Unit testing a model like this? I use Nunit and Rhino mocks.

```
public class Checkbox
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public HtmlString LabelText { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string ShowElement { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string ngModel { get; set; }
    public string ngChange { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can only test stuff that actually DOES anything. Your class does not do anything, so what to test?

Comment: Is there no way of let's say setting the Id field as something, then retrieving it and seeing it it comes back properly?

Comment: Sure you can, create an instance of your class, set its property and then get its value. Then check if the value you´ve got is equal to the provided one by using an assert-statement. That´s the way EVERY test works.

Comment: @M.James what exactly you're trying to test in this manner: "assign value to the property of class, then retrieve it back and compare with assigned one"? This makes no sense at all when we're talking about autoimplemented properties since this kind of test will **always** pass.

Comment: That was my thought, So there's never a point in testing them really, I have seen other people testing them and wondered if I had missed something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in testing your model. If you've been using mocks and testing your controllers that's great! But if you really want to be creative in your testing I would focus on other things like services/api's, seeing how your components behave with them and asserting accordingly.

What you're really doing testing a model is this:

```
var x = "myexpectedstring"
var y = "myexpectedstring"

Assert.Equal(x, y);
```